# How to interpret this learning curve plot

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forests

Bellow I have a Learning Curve plot How should I interpret this plot for my random forrest algorithm (the second one the most complex one)? 
Which one is the best?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the X index is training set size. For the first and second case, teh training set size starts at 0(or 1). The model will overfit certainly at that data size. When data size increases, the model overfits less and less and eventually the model have enough data samples that it won't overfit. The data size continue to increase and the model performance increase as well. To a certain point, the validation loss increase start to diminish and the model slightly overfits the samples.  For the third graph, it seems like originally teh loss is low and started to increase.
Hopes it help